# ComboBox Vanishes and never comes back

Tags: vba, excel

Good Evening All,

I am trying to increase usability to a workbook by having an activex combobox vanishes when it's not needed to reduce confusion when creating a chart.
The problem is, once it vanishes, it never comes back.
Do I need to add more to my code? Is this actually just deleting my combobox?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Cells(1, 1).Value > "0" Then
        Me.ComboBox2.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.ComboBox2.Visible = False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to work OK for me, try stepping through your code make sure you're running the line `Me.ComboBox2.Visible = True`

Comment: maybe `If Cells(1, 1).Value > 0` (remove quotes around `0`)?

Comment: Remove the whole IF block and just use `Me.ComboBox2.Visible = (Cells(1, 1).Value > 0)`, no need to toggle ScreenUpdating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to remove double quotes around `0`

furthermore your code can be simplified to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    Me.ComboBox2.Visible = Cells(1, 1).value > 0
End Sub
```

Comment: the actual solution to the problem was `Me.ComboBox2.Visible = Cells(1, 1).Value = 0` but thanks for helping me solve the issue. I wanted the combobox to be visible when there was nothing in the target cell. Your code helped me get rid of the `If` statements which is awesome.